# A public apology to the mods

Tags: discussion

I'm busy in the next couple of weeks to update the grammar of some of my old post. I have noticed that an edit brings the question back to the top spot on the main page.

I realise that having a bunch of old questions on the main page is less than ideal. The thing is just I would like to use my presence on this site in job applications and I don't want my posts to give the impression of an uneducated person.

So just an apology for any inconvenience I may provide,

Thank You

Neil

Comment: This actually caused the system to flag you as possibly defacing your posts -- I declined it since obviously you were doing the opposite :P

Answer (score 2):

it shouldn't really be a problem.

In extremis it does flood the front page, so if you can moderate it a wee bit that helps, but I understand your reasons and it makes sense.

Another thing you can do if you are bumping a question anyway is quickly check if the answers need any work, or if there are any comments that should be flagged.